# Overloading Arithmetic Operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

The assignment operator can be declared as

T& operator= (const t&);

in a class, but the arithmetic operators cannot be defined that way. It has to be friend function. I don't understand why? Can you please explain ?

Answer (score 4):

It is not mandatory that arithmetic operators should be friend

Well you can define like this:

```
MyClass MyClass::operator + (const MyClass& t) const
{
  MyClass ret(*this);
  ret += t;
  return ret;
}
```

The `a + b` is really a syntax sugar, the compiler will expand it to `a.operator+(b)`. The previous sample will work if all your objects are MyClass instances, but will not work if you have to operate with others types, ie `1 + a`, will not work, this can be solved by using friends.

```
MyClass operator + (int i, const MyClass& t)
{
  MyClass ret(i);
  ret += t;
  return ret;
}
```

This has to be done when the left hand side of the + operator is not a class, or it is a class but you can't add operator + to its definition.

Answer (score 2):

They ideally should be globals and not necessarily friends, so that you can write:

```
yourtype v = 1;
yourtype w = 1 + v;
```

Since, 1 is not an object of `yourtype`, if the `operator+` were a member it would throw a fit. However, making it global makes it convert the 1 to `yourtype` and then perform the operation. Making it a friend helps to extract and manipulate the members of `yourtype` as required -- though not required. As an example: You can implement the member function `operator+=` and use it in the implementation of the `operator+`.

Answer (score 2):

I think that [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html) will give you a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you do something like this:

```
class A
{
    A& operator+(int n);
    // ...
}

int main()
{
    A my_var;
    int integer = 1;
    A + integer; // compiles
    integer + A // error: no function operator+(int, A) defined
}
```

it will not compile.
A solution is to define operator+(int, A) and operator+(A, int) as friends of A.
As a side note, the Boost Operators library makes this process very easy.